# keyof typeof Module not working with interfaces

Tags: typescript

I want to create a dynamic type that is a union of interface symbols.
Given a file "MyInterfaces.ts"

```
export interface SomeInterfaceA {}
export interface SomeInterfaceB {}
...
export interface SomeInterfaceZ {}
```

I have the following definition:

```
import * as AllMyInterfaces from "./MyInterfaces"

type InterfaceNames = keyof typeof AllMyInterfaces
const test: InterfaceNames = "SomeInterfaceA"
//^^^^^^^^^ TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

But the compiler says: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Somehow, the result of "typeof AllMyInterfaces" does not contain any interface symbol.
How do I have to define my Union type to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Exported types (such as interfaces) don't actually add anything to the exported module. The `keyof` type operator therefore ignores "type fields" for star imports.

This is also more intuitive when shown using this example module:

```js
export const ABC = 123;
export type Def = number;
```

The following code would produce the following output:

```js
import * as MyModule from './module';
Object.keys(MyModule); // ['ABC']
```

So it makes sense that the `keyof` operator ignores the types.

Comment: Well, thanks for the explanation of the cause so far. Do you have a solution for this problem? How to collect the interfaces?

Comment: You can create another interface that contains these other interfaces as fields. E.g. `interface AllMyInterfaces { SomeInterfaceA: SomeInterfaceA; }` which allows you to use `keyof AllMyInterfaces` _(even after importing that type wherever)_

Comment: This would be the same (amount of work / loose of type connection) as to define InterfaceNames as 
    `type InterfaceNames = "SomeInterfaceA" | "SomeInterfaceB" | ... | "SomeInterfaceZ"`

There are a huge number of interface and they may change from time to time. So I realy need some sort of generic solution here.

Comment: @Zomono correct, but there isn't much else you can do. You can always try to make a feature request (or even pull request) on the TypeScript repository on GitHub, but that's of course a long process.